# SOAP return Unexpected subelement but elements are in WSDL

Tags: soap, postman, wsdl

I have WSDL file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa" xmlns:appinfo="http://appinfo.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:ax217="http://einlieferung.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:ax218="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:ax230="http://infopool.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:hma="http://hma.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd">
            <xs:complexType name="Identifikation">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Deprecated! Wird nirgends verwendet.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="adresse" nillable="true" type="ax218:Kontaktdaten"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="adresseAnsprechpartner" nillable="true" type="ax218:Kontaktdaten"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ik" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa" xmlns:ax220="http://einlieferung.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd" xmlns:ax221="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd">
            <xs:import namespace="http://einlieferung.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://infopool.ws.bswsnt.vsa/xsd"/>
            <xs:element name="sendKostenvoranschlagData">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="kv" nillable="true" type="ax217:Einlieferung"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="identifikation" nillable="true" type="ax218:Identifikation">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Deprecated! Wird nicht verwendet.</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="sendKostenvoranschlagDataResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="ax218:Statusmeldung"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="sendKostenvoranschlagDataRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="xsd:sendKostenvoranschlagData" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="BswSchnittstellePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="sendKostenvoranschlagData">
            <wsdl:documentation>Übermittlung von Kostenvoranschlägen.</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="xsd:sendKostenvoranschlagDataRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:sendKostenvoranschlagData"/>
            <wsdl:output message="xsd:sendKostenvoranschlagDataResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:sendKostenvoranschlagDataResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BswSchnittstelleSoap12Binding" type="xsd:BswSchnittstellePortType">
        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="sendKostenvoranschlagData">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:sendKostenvoranschlagData" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BswSchnittstelleHttpBinding" type="xsd:BswSchnittstellePortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="sendKostenvoranschlagData">
            <http:operation location="BswSchnittstelle2/sendKostenvoranschlagData"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content part="sendKostenvoranschlagData" type="text/xml"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content part="sendKostenvoranschlagData" type="text/xml"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="BswSchnittstelle2">
        <wsdl:port binding="xsd:BswSchnittstelleHttpBinding" name="BswSchnittstelleHttpEndpoint">
            <http:address location="https://azhtrial.noventi.healthcare/services/test/BswSchnittstelle2"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port binding="xsd:BswSchnittstelleSoap11Binding" name="BswSchnittstelleHttpSoap11Endpoint">
            <soap:address location="https://azhtrial.noventi.healthcare/services/test/BswSchnittstelle2"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port binding="xsd:BswSchnittstelleSoap12Binding" name="BswSchnittstelleHttpSoap12Endpoint">
            <soap12:address location="https://azhtrial.noventi.healthcare/services/test/BswSchnittstelle2"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I created the SOAP envelope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
         <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password>xxx</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <sendKostenvoranschlagData xmlns="http://ws.bswsnt.vsa">
    <identifikation>
        <ik>123445</ik>
      </identifikation>
    </sendKostenvoranschlagData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I get the error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement ik</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I am doing wrong?